# What is a meaning of this William Shakespeare's quote?

Tags: sentence-meaning, archaic-language

My problem is understanding of following quote:

> "There were no age between ten and three-and-twenty, or that youth
>   would sleep out the rest; for there is nothing in the between but
>   getting wenches with child, wronging the ancientry, stealing,
>   fighting."

I will highly appreciate if someone could paraphrase this quote to be more easy than it is now.

A little more context

> Through the ages, most answers have cited dark forces that uniquely
>   affect the teen. Aristotle concluded more than 2,300 years ago that
>   "the young are heated by Nature as drunken men by wine." A shepherd in
>   William Shakespeare's The Winter's Tale wishes "there were no age
>   between ten and three-and-twenty, or that youth would sleep out the
>   rest; for there is nothing in the between but getting wenches with
>   child, wronging the ancientry, stealing, fighting."

Comment: Could you provide more context, please? What play/act/scene is this from?

Comment: Maybe "between sixteen and three-and twenty'?

Comment: Does your text say "ten"?

Comment: What do you understand about this passage? Please be more specific about which parts you're having trouble with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with usages that are completely obsolete, so it would be better answered on [English.SE].

Comment: @NathanTuggy I don't think this would be on-topic on ELU. There's got to be a modern version of the work and I don't see any point welcoming this kind of question on ELU. It will be closed probably for lack of research unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified with proper research.

Comment: @Rathony: OK, but just because there's not enough research for ELU to accept this does not mean it belongs on ELL.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Absolutamente. It is up to ELL to decide whether to close it or not. For myself, I am reluctant to vote to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would paraphrase this as:

> I wish that youth either skipped from age ten to age 23, or that they would sleep during all these years, because there is nothing good between the ages of 10 and 23 except teens sexual exploits, including teen pregnancy, doing mean things to older people, stealing, and fighting.

Essentially, those years between the ages of 10 and 23 are the time when people bring upon themselves, and others, much misery and pain, and if you could skip those years, life would be better for everybody.

Answer (score 3):

The quote expresses his distaste for individuals between the ages of ten and twenty-three; if they went to sleep at age ten and woke up at twenty-three nothing would be lost, because all they do between those ages is have sex, harass elders, steal, and fight.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the old shepherd meant that he wished that young people aged between sixteen and twenty-three either hibernated through this period of their lives or didn't exist at all because they, being unruly and destructive, create too many troubles for others.

By the way, it's from Winter's Tale, act 3, scene 3.

Comment: a) There is no justification for the 19th century emendation 'sixteen'--the only source has 'ten'. b) I think 'no age between...' means '[boys] jumped directly from ten to 23' rather than 'didn't exist at all' c) I think there might be some value in explaining that "getting wenches with child" means "making girls pregnant" and that "wronging the ancientry" means "annoying old people".

Comment: Good additions, StoneyB